# Retrieving a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the list `mydicts = []` which contains

```
[{'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
    'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
    'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
    'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0} }]
```

I am however trying to get it in this format in order for me to perform some operations:

```
d = {'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0} }
```

I tried doing this

```
sm_list = list(mydicts)
d = sm_list
```

But it did not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just access to it by using [list indices:](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

```
my_dicts = [{'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
    'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
    'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
    'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0} }]

d = my_dicts[0]
```

**Notes:**

- The proper name for `[...]` is **list**, not array.
- By accessing to `my_dicts[0]`, you are accessing to the *first* element. With `my_dicts[1]` you will access to the second element. And so on.
- When you do `list(mydicts)`, it doesn't have effect because `my_dicts` is already a list.

Comment: +1: Someone went on a downvote run on your answers. Upvoting for correct approach, correcting *list* and not *array*, and the final tip for accessing elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue simply by doing this:

```
d = mydicts[0]
```

This returns the first value from `mydicts`, which conveniently is exactly what you want.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain themselves? I am always looking to improve my posts.

Comment: There's an *idiot* who downvoted all answers at the same time, even though the answers are *correct*. Here, take my upvote. +1.

Comment: @BK201 Thank you very much. It really annoys you when you don't have alot of reputation to fall back on.

Comment: I think is because the answer is extremely easy. Feels like cheating :) I also got my own -1 :P

Comment: @PauloBu Come on, it's easy rep. (Err... I mean.. I love to help the community *cough, cough*). One has to jump at the opportunity when there are millions of users.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be obtained by retrieving the first (and only) element in your array -- which is already what Python calls a`list` -- since it's exactly what you seek. The first element in a list/array is the one with an index of 0.

```
mydicts = [{'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
            'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
            'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
            'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},}]

d = mydicts[0]

print "d's contents: {"
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print '    {}: {},'.format(k, v)
print '}'
```

Output:

```
d's contents: {
    Frank: {'Sam': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
    Sam: {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
    Kevin: {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
    Jack: {'Frank': 0, 'Sam': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
}
```